# jQuery selector on a string only works when surrounded by a div

Tags: jquery

Why does this work?

```
$('#findme', '<div><div id="findme">Hello</div></div>')
```

And this does not?

```
$('#findme', '<div id="findme">Hello</div>')
```

For some reason only when I have the enclosing div will jQuery find the div with the id of findme.

Even enclosing it in a different tag does not work.

```
$('#findme', '<html><div id="findme">Hello</div></html>')
```

In addition the following don't work.

```
$('<div id="findme">Hello</div>').find('#findme')
$('<html><div id="findme">Hello</div></html>').find('#findme')
```

Although this works.

```
$('<div><div id="findme">Hello</div></div>').find('#findme')
```

There is something I'm not understanding about how the context works.

Thanks,
Randall

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is quite easy actually. The way you are searching is using context. So it takes the top-most node in the string, and searches through it's children.

So imagine having the same structure in html, and parsing it:

```
$('#findme', '<div><div id="findme"></div></div>')
```

is the same as

```
$('div').find('#findme')
```

**OR**

```
$('div').children('#findme')
```

---

So when you try

```
$('<div id="findme"></div>').find('#findme')
```

It obviously has no children.

Comment: I believe it's not ".findme" but "#findme" in your examples. Aside from that, well explained indeed

Comment: I find it odd the div with the enclosed html tag doesn't work either. Does this mean it is impossible to select a top level div in a string?

Comment: @Randall: if you know the string is only a div, doing $('<div id="findme">Hello</div>') is essentially creating the DIV you are looking for - you don't have to find it!

Comment: Not sure about the html tag, but I doubt thats often encountered.

Comment: @Randall: As the jQuery documentation notes: "Simple elements without attributes, e.g., "<div />", are created via document.createElement. All other cases are parsed by assigning the string to the .innerHTML property of a div element. The HTML string cannot contain elements that are invalid within a div, such as html, head, body, or title elements." http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#elements